# mod_rewrite - redirecting to several different PHP files

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want any request to /files/ to be redirected to one php script, and all others (that aren't for specific file types) to be directed to another. No matter what I try I can't get this to work. This is from my apache2 virtual server config file:

```
<Directory /var/www/test/public>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /files
RewriteRule ~files/(.+) file-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|php|ico|html|js|xml|flv)$ /index.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI}

</Directory>
```

I also tried this:

```
<Directory /var/www/test/public>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|php|ico|html|js|xml|flv)$ /index.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteBase /files
RewriteRule ~files/(.+) file-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

</Directory>
```

Comment: shoud not be "RewriteBase /" ?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Virtual Hosts? < VirtualHost> section should have "RewriteOptions Inherit"

Comment: That may be the answer, I am using virtual Hosts and I didn't use that. I will test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't solve this, but found a work around - I just redirect to a single PHP file and then do the logic in there. Don't know why I didn't think of that before...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with RewriteBase and/or the ~file match.  Did you try just using one base, and using that for your rules?  Not totally sure what you are trying with your rules, but

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^files/(.+) /file-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule !.(pdf|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|php|ico|html|js|xml|flv)$ /index.php [L,QSA]`

You can just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP directly.

The other path to try is multiple `<Directory>` sections (one for the subdir and one for the root).

But, as you noted, just punting into a single PHP file and redirecting there is often easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond ^files/(.*)\.(pdf|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|php|ico|html|js|xml|flv)$
RewriteRule file-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Not tested, but I think it will work.

First line: match any requests for www.example.com/files/*.<file types in list above>

Second line: redirect that match to file-handler.php?id=<match from above>

Third line: match everything else

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) file-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|php|ico|html|js|xml|flv)$
RewriteRule !^files/ /index.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first rule matches every request that’s URI path (without the contextual path prefix, see [`RewriteBase` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)) starts with `files/`. And the second rules matches every request that’s path does neither start with `files/` nor ends with one of the listed file name extensions.